# Pass parameter client to server-side with RIA services

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I'm using RIA Services with EF and a Silverlight UI and the built-in validation framework. Problem is the following:

The validation rules differ slightly based on user-input client-side, consider this simple scenario.

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext  validationContext)
{
    if (validation_mode == Modes.Normal)
    {
        // do normal validation
    }
    else
    {
        // do admin validation
    }
}
```

I'd like a way to pass the 'validation_mode' to RIA services, server-side. Can i somehow pass it to the ValidationContext.Items collection? Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the validation_mode to the ValidationContext:

```
ValidationContext.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<object,object>("validation_mode", validation_mode));
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to get passed-down to the server side?

Comment: You can create a server-side method and call it client-side like this:

    [Invoke]
    public void SetItem(string value)
    {
        this.ValidationContext.Items.Add("key", value);
    }

The domainservice looses state though, so this value is not always available... Thoughts?

Comment: How did you determine it is not propegated to the server side? We just add an item to a open list of validation items. Maybe convert validation_mode to a string before entering it in the KeyValuePair?

Comment: Well, where are you accessing the validationcontext?